# How to install javax.media on the pc in order to use jipcam

Tags: java, media

I want to use `jipcam` library to work with AXIS network camera which streams MJPEG video through my network. In order to do so I need to install `javax.media` on my computer so imports like those below will work. 
I can't find any source to install those libraries. I use JDK 1.7. Eclipse and Windows 8.1 Does anone knows how to install `javax.media` on  my computer?

```
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceInfo;
import javax.media.CaptureDeviceManager;
import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.control.FormatControl;
import javax.media.format.JPEGFormat;
import javax.media.protocol.CaptureDevice;
```

Jipcam: http://jipcam.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.media` is provided by JMF, the Java Media Framework. Setup instructions are [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/setup-138642.html).

Comment: I had to add jmf.jar to build path of the project is there any way to merge it with java istalled on the computer?

Comment: I think you can move it to `jre/lib/ext`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html